# how to Installing JSON on PHP Version 5.1.6?

Tags: php, json

I am running PHP 5.1.6, how can I install the PHP JSON extension?

Comment: JSON is a storage format, not a software product. What do you want to do?

Comment: Strange that this was voted as not a real question. I understood what it meant and this is exactly what I was looking for as well. Perhaps pointing @user1021829 to serverfault may have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade your php version. php 5.2.0 or higher version support json.

Comment: +1: And running unsupported versions of PHP is a good way to have security vulnerabilities.